# What is the equivalent of Mac OS X Spaces for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-desktop

I am looking for a utility that does the same task done by Spaces for Mac OS X.
For who doesn't know it, it's a utility that allows you to create virtual screens in order to not have all the screens in a single screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) from Sysinternals.

[image]
[image]

Alternatively, there is [WindowsPager](http://windowspager.sourceforge.net/) which is also free.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Which one would you suggest to use on a netbook running Window 7 Starter with 1 GB of RAM?

Comment: You're welcome. "Desktops" should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Windows now includes a feature called Task View which is very similar to macOS's Mission Control/Spaces. In the Windows 10 taskbar, click the "Task View" button on the right of the search bar to add desktops and switch between them.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1542904) on a similar question has more detail.

Comment: I know this question was originally asked about Windows 7, but it is still the top search result when I was searching the same question for Windows 10. So hopefully this is helpful to someone else!

Comment: It seems it is helpful as this is now Google's featured answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could try out VirtuaWin ( http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/ ). It's pretty lightweight, opensource and also a portable application.  (and yes, despite not beeing mentioned on the projects frontpage, it's also working on Win7.

Answer (score 1):

[Finestra Virtual Desktops](http://vdm.codeplex.com/) from codeplex is also free and not too bad